# Multidimensional label data on Caffe

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I plan to implement a CNN that can estimate depth from single images by using NYU depth v2 dataset. Going through the tutorial has shown me that it is easy to implement a CNN which deals with a classification problem on Caffe. I'm curious that if Caffe is suited for a task that involves multidimensional ground truths (e.g. depth image) and regression (depth estimation).

What I want to achieve is to use depth images as ground truths to train a CNN that can estimate depth images. I need to load labels as single channel image data.

I could only find this answer by Shelhamer that is related to my problem https://groups.google.com/d/msg/caffe-users/JXmZrz4cCMU/mBTU1__ohg4J

I understand that I should define two top layers, one for input and the other for depth data as ground truth. Then I can use a loss layer (like EucledianLoss) to calculate loss. I've added a model below.

Is this model going to work as intended?  If not, is there any other way to do it on Caffe?

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data" 
  image_data_param {
    source: "input_set.txt"
    batch_size: 50
  }
}

layer {
  name: "label"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "label"
  image_data_param {
    source: "depth_set.txt"
    batch_size: 50
  }
  is_color: false
}

layer {
 name: "loss"
 type: "EuclideanLoss"
 bottom: "some_output_layer_name"
 bottom: "label"
 top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: Have you achieved your results? I have been trying the same thing. But I couldnt come up with a network which fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my above model was correct way to start but has some problems. If you have labels as images you can use `ImageData` layer provided in caffe. `ImageData` has 2 top layers, first is the actual image data and the second one is its "label" which is a number (used for simple classification problems). In your source file you can provide path to your label data and put some arbitrary "label"s and just ignore these. `ignored1` and `ignored2` below corresponds to these ignored labels.

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "ignored1"
  image_data_param {
    source: "path/to/data/data.txt"
    batch_size: 32
    new_height: 228
    new_width: 304
  }
}

# Label data
layer {
  name: "depth"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "depth"
  top: "ignored2"
  image_data_param {
    is_color: false
    source: "path/to/data/labels.txt"
    batch_size: 32
    new_height: 55
    new_width: 74
  }
}
```

data.txt sample:

```
/path/to/your/data/1.png 0
/path/to/your/data/2.png 0
/path/to/your/data/3.png 0
...
```

labels.txt sample:

```
/path/to/your/labels/1.png 0
/path/to/your/labels/2.png 0
/path/to/your/labels/3.png 0
...
```

Alternatively you can write your own Python layer to read your image and label data. Here's an [example layer](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/nyud_layers.py) to read NYUDv2 data.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the above model should work the way you expected it to work. Just make sure that the dimensions of `some_output_layer_name` blob is same as that of `label` blob.